# Adding a guest member with Read Only Access

Tags: azure-devops

I must add an external guest user to 3 Azure DevOps Projects with only read access. They should be able to check out but not check in source code.

I think I know how to do this.

1. Add the external user to Azure AD using information in this link.
2. Sign in to our DevOps org.
3. Select gear icon Organization Settings in the lower left-hand of the screen.
4. Select Users.
5. Click “Add users”
6. Enter the Users name, set the access level to Stakeholder, select the projects to add the users to, and set group to Project Reads. Then click Add.

Is there any more to it than this?

Comment: Patrick, yes this was very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> set the access level to Stakeholder

**User with Stakeholder access level are not able to access Azure Repos for private project**.

Features not available to users with Stakeholder access

If a Stakeholder needs access to one or more of the following features—which support the daily work of product owners, team leads, developers, testers, and project administrators—you need to have **Basic** access.

*For Private projects:*

- Change the priority of an item within a backlog
- Delete work items or move work items to another project
- Create shared queries, view charts, and modify the home page
- View Delivery Plans (a Marketplace extension)
- **Access the full set of features under Pipelines, Repos or Test Plans.**

If you give that user only with Stackholder access, he will even not be able to see Repos button in navigation bar.

[image]

So, you need either assign this user Basic access or make those three Azure DevOps Projects as a [Public Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/about-public-projects?view=azure-devops).

More details about Stakeholder, please take a look at our official doc here-- [Get started as a Stakeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)